# html/php contact form template not sending email

Tags: php, html

I'm using an html/php form template that I found. Every time I try to submit a completed form, I get a 405 error.

I want the submit button to send the contents of the form to my email address.

Heres the html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="../assets/php/actionpage.php" name="emailform" method="POST">
        <div class="row mb--20">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6 form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6 form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6 form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6 form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Website" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 form-group">
                <textarea cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-6 form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn--border-primary"><input type="submit" value="submit"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This doesn't look out of the ordinary to me. So I think the problem is with the php.

actionpage.php:

```
<?php
if ( !empty($_POST) ) {}

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page shouldn't be accesed directly
    echo "ERROR: you need to submit the form!";
    exit;
}

// Collect
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$email = $_POST['E-mail'];
$phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$website = $_POST['Website'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];


// Validate
if(empty($name)||empty($email)||empty($message))
{
    echo "Name, E-mail, and Message are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = $email;
$email_subject = "New Form Submission";
$email_body = "You have a new email from: $name\n their email: $email\n phone number: $phone\n and their website: $website\n Here is their message: $message";

$to = "##@###.##" // my email
$headers = "From $email_from \r\n";

// Send
mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers);

// redirect

header('Location: index.html');

?>
```

I am very new to php, so I decided to use a template.

I'm testing this using LiveServer in VScode. Is that having an impact?

Comment: `$POST` is not the same as `$_POST`, `$email` is not the same as `$emailaddress`. and `$errors` isn't defined before you try to append to it. You're also missing a semi-colon at the end of your mail statement.

Comment: Also known as "remember to look at PHP's console/log output" because it should be yelling about all these things (unless you have warnings/errors turned off instead of having them get written to a log file, in which case: definitely fix that)

Comment: `I'm testing this using LiveServer in VScode`...yes, it's just a super-basic server for testing static or javascript based pages. It can't handle POST requests (hence the 405) and it can't execute PHP scripts either. You need a proper webserver such as IIS or Apache with php installed

Comment: In addition to @ADyson's comment, you probably want **index.php** to redirect to and not **html**.  Also, the user will be left rather confused when the **submit** takes him to the home page.  In my contact form, I handle the submitted code in the same form and echo the whole form without the submit button and with a confirmation message.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: add name values to your form. Then every aspect will work okay. or use jquery to process and submit the form as is.